# I was run my webscraping code but got this error ??(NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5876) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

How to solve this type of error any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws an error at some point in some promise. You can solve it by properly handling the exception.

Ex:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Some code
});

p.then(res => {
    // No errors thrown
}).catch(err => {
    // Exception happened. Print the error
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Or using [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) if you are working with async processes using `async / await`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, try this but same error display @Berkays

Comment: @Natarajan Can you share the related code?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply @Berkays my issue solved